# IDA Pro: Where does newly created structure go to from Pseudocode window?

Tags: ida, hexrays

Where does newly created structure go to from Pseudocode window? I'm referring to structure that you create via right-click on variable and choosing "Create new struct type".

I don't see new structure in `View / Open Subviews / Structures` but I'd like to modify it afterwards.

[image]

I'm using IDA Pro 6.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The created types get added to the Local Types list (View->Open subviews->Local types, or <kbd>Shift-F1</kbd>). To jump directly to the specific type, choose "Jump to local type..." from the context menu on a variable of that type.

You can import any structure from Local Types to the Structures list by double-clicking it or selecting "Syncronize to idb" from the context menu.

Additionally, the structure gets imported automatically if you select "Jump to structure definition" (<kbd>Z</kbd>) on any of its fields in the pseudocode.

Comment: Thank you! I have loosely related question. After I deleted local type my Decompiled got botched and I'm no longer able to use it (http://i.snag.gy/40Teb.jpg). How can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ins</kbd> in the Structures view, press the **Add standard structure** button, and you'll find in that list the struct you created via the Pseudocode view, which you can then double-click to add it to the list of structures in the Structures view.

Unintuitive, I know; it would be nice for it to *automatically* get added to the list of structures in the Structures view.

Comment: Seriously? You don't just use Local Types?

Comment: Oh yeah, looks like that would work too :)

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky No, because when I press `T` in an operand to set a structure offset, only structures in the Structures window are available. Why is there 2 different sets of structures in the program? It's even bigger pain to work with them in Python.